# problemas implementando parallel de php

Tags: php, wampserver

me presento por acá con un problema que tengo días dándole vueltas y no he logrado solventar, debido a unos procesos que se deben realizar en el sistema administrativo de mi trabajo hemos decidió implementar la tecnología de los subprocesos para dar mayor agilidad, el tema es que he instalado parallel (php_parallel-1.1.4-7.3-ts-vc15-x64.zip descargado de https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/parallel) siguiendo las instrucciones presentes en la pagina de php(https://www.php.net/manual/en/parallel.setup.php) seguí paso a paso las instrucciones tal como se describen allí, al final realice la validación por CMD tal como lo indican y no me arroja ningún problema(esta es la respuesta de la consola al ejecutar el comadno php -v:

> PHP 7.3.21 (cli) (built: Aug  4 2020 11:21:19) ( ZTS MSVC15 (Visual
> C++ 2017) x64 ) Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group Zend Engine
> v3.3.21, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies),

Pero al momento de implementar un código de prueba este no funciona dando el siguiente error:

> "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'parallel\Runtime' not found"

No entiendo que me puede estar faltando por realizar, no se si me falta algún include o algo por hacer? agradecería cualquier ayuda o consejo que me puedan brindar

adjunto mi phpinfo y el código de prueba que estoy utilizando:

```
`<?php

use \parallel\{Runtime, Future, Channel, Events};

$rt = new \parallel\Runtime();

$rt->run(function(){
 for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++)
 echo "+";
});

for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) 
 echo "-";


?>
`
```

[image: info de php]

Comment: Primero tendrías que indicar cómo habilitaste el ZTS y detallar si instalaste por paquete, por compilación o por binario.

Comment: ps la instalación del parallel fue el binario y la descargue de https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/parallel/1.1.4/php_parallel-1.1.4-7.3-ts-vc15-x64.zip y lo del ZTS aplique la misma configuración que tienen puesta en el servidor de producción, ¿quizás sea alguna de esos dos pasos? o ¿me falto alguno?